# How to implement Android Custom Store

Tags: android

One of our customers wants to acquire a private android-store, he wants to publish android apps that he will sell to his users and have the full-control of the billing part of its store.

I have no idea about this kind of implementation so I ask your help to guide me to understand what must be done to achieve this task, I'm interested by any link speaking about the "custom android store" architecture or something similar,

I have already seen "Google Store Private Channel" but I think that is not possible to attach a billing module on it, if so we will not be able to use it.

Comment: Do you want to build an alternative to Google Play, something like Amazon App store?

Comment: Hi Axarydax, thanks for your replay, Yes we want to implement an alternative to Google play